# Global search in Xcode 10.1

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I'm trying to search through my entire project using CMD + SHIFT + F.

When I'm searching for anything that contains a dot (.) in the query the search will not find anything even though I literally just copied it from the code. For example I am searching for this:

> self.init

and I get "no results for self.init"

I can't find any option that maybe regular expressions would be activated.

How can I make XCode to find any string I type into the search field (even when it contains dots)?

Comment: Hey OP, have you had a chance to check out my answer?

Comment: sorry for the late responde. literally minutes after I posted it I figured out the solution. and well yeah, it's the same you posted. so I'm picking it as the correct answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>, or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to open the left side menu. In there, you can search using regular text search, regex, and more.

When searching for plain text, make sure that you're not matching regex. For this, press the button next to *Find* and select *Text* from the dropdown:

[image]